# TS - Reduce an array of objects to an object

Tags: typescript, reduce

I want to convert an array of objects to an object

```
var arrays = [
    {key:'k1',value:'v1'},
    {key:'k2',value:'v2'},
    {key:'k3',value:'v3'}
];
```

to

```
{k1: "v1", k2: "v2", k3: "v3"}
```

This works

```
const object: {[k: string]: any} = {};
arrays.forEach((item) => { object[item.key] = item.value });
```

But I'd like how to do it using reduce.

```
const customData = arrays.reduce((obj, item) => (obj: Record<string, any>) => (obj[item.key] = item.value, obj), {});
```

returns

```
(obj) => (obj[item.key] = item.value)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just remove the `(obj: Record<string, any>) =>` from your code

Comment: Why use reduce?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The callback inside `reduce` is not supposed to return a function but the intermediate value after the current item has been processed – in your case the object after you've assigned the current item to it.

```
const customData = array.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj[item.key] = item.value;
  return obj;
}, {} as Record<string, string>)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAnjAvDA2gWAFAyEwDeA1gKYoBcA5KQIw0A0AbnADYCu5tLjAvk3xESFanQBMzNlx40WUwcKJlKtUgGZpHbry398AXQDc%20fKEixgnaCAC2AEThQ4GeElQA6BOQAmnYHIACiCQACMAKyYYAEsocjsASgwAPhJlcIisOITPMUM3HLtPGW5TAhgfKE4EMBhM8sESfngIGAAlclAEXwAeaAQYsABzaIGh4ZTE8vNwCBB2ck92EGGg61tHZzhpmAB6PdF6KhgAIj5T6NIJE-OJS5hNW5YNU-4gA)

Comment: Thanks, I like this solution best since it's closest to mine. But @Sandeep's solution below is also good and very descriptive.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with your code is TypeScript compiler could not infer the return type, not the object type. So, you don't need `Record<string, any>` for individual object which typescript can infer by itself. You would need to pass in the type of the result you would expect.

You could do it simply like this,

```
var arrays = [
  { key:'k1',value:'v1' },
  { key:'k2',value:'v2' },
  { key:'k3',value:'v3' }
];

const result = arrays.reduce((prev: {[key: string]: string}, curr) => {
   prev[curr.key] = curr.value;
   return prev;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Note: the result type is added in order for typescript to figure out the result type.

And, you can write that with shorthand syntax,

```
const result = arrays.reduce((prev: {[key: string]: string}, curr) =>  
  ({ ...prev, [curr.key]: curr.value}), {})
```

Comment: Careful, the shorthand version has quadratic time complexity.